# Django 2: unresolved attribute reference 'get_queryset' for class

Tags: django, django-models

get_queryset is not work in model manager

## models.py

## model manager

```
class ProductManager(models.Model):
    def featured(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(featured=True)
```

I'm trying to solve this problem using supper class. But isn't work

```
return super(ProductManager, self).get_queryset().filter(featured=True)
```

## model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path, null=True, blank=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = ProductManager()
```

## Error

> AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'featured'

## views.py

```
class ProductListFeaturedView(ListView):
    # model = Product
    template_name = 'products/list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.featured()
```

first time i'm facing this problem.

Comment: If ProductManager is a manager, shouldn't it inherit from models.Manager not models.Model?

Comment: Thanks for this.